# Why do my slideshow images appear briefly before fading in?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a real estate website and I am wanting to have an image slideshow with photos of the property on the site. I'm using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript to do this.

Everything seems to be working fine, except I have a problem with opacity. My images are shown for a split second before the opacity goes to 0. I've inspected the slideshow in my Chrome devtools and that is how I know it's an opacity problem. Please let me know if you guys can find what's wrong in my code! I appreciate it!

**HTML code**

```
<!-- SLIDESHOW -->

<div class="slideshow-container">

        <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
          <img src="img/main.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
          <img src="img/malibu.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
          <img src="img/test-img.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
        </div>

        <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
      </div>
      <br>

      <!-- The dots/circles -->
      <div style="text-align:center">
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
      </div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
body {
  font-family: Verdana, 
  sans-serif; margin:0
}
.mySlides {
   display: none
}
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: 0} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: 0} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

Comment: Does the problem occur here? https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/8r5ohq0t/

Comment: You might have to play around with the opacity from value or with the animation type and duration to get it to your liking really.  Another option might be to do something with the .slideshow-container background

Comment: I don't actually see a problem in the Fiddle, unless you are looking for a different sort of effect.  You might need a ';' after the number here:   [from {opacity: 0}]

Comment: @isherwood In the Fiddle it works fine. Did you change anything specific in the Fiddle to make it work?

Comment: No. I was hoping to see it in action. Just updated image paths.

Comment: Yeah that's strange. It works fine in fiddle, but in the browser it only shows the images for a second before it turns white and opacity is down to 0.

Answer (score -1):

Try to set  `animation-duration: 0s`

Comment: This just eliminates the fade effect. How is that helpful?

Comment: Because fade has animation duration of 1.5s and it changes opacity

Comment: @isherwood is right. It only eliminates the fade. The images are now completely gone.

Answer (score -1):

Just add this code below your JS code.

```
var autoslideIndex = 0;
autoSlides();  
function autoSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides= document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  autoslideIndex++;
  if (autoslideIndex > slides.length) {autoslideIndex  = 1}    
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[autoslideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[autoslideIndex-1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(autoSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

Comment: this is automating the transition of the images. I want it to be up to the user. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Yes, it covers automatic + user click slideshow, which should be the ideal way. I am not sure why it is devoted. We are here to help you in best possible way.

Comment: That does not make sense. The automatic is not what I'm looking for. Thank you thought